# Induced emf of a loop

Tags: electromagnetism

We know from the classical example in physics where we have two rails separated by a distance "L" and we have a bar also of length "L" rolling across the rail where it is in a uniform magnetic field. As shown below. Now if I wanted to find the emf across the rail I would apply faraday's law of induction where the change in flux is due to the change in area. However, why can we do that? Doesn't Faraday's law only hold if we were to make a closed loop (i.e shouldn't that emf we get from faraday's law give us the potention if we were to start at some arbitrary point and make a loop around the rail ending at itself?)[image]

Comment: I don't get the question. You do have a closed loop. It consists of the bar, the top rail, the wire, and the bottom rail.

Comment: @AaronStevens In another words, Faraday's law says the contour integral of the induced electric field dotted with a differential element of the loop is equal to the change in flux with respect to time. However, if we wanted the potential difference across the bar why can we just say its the change in flux. Doesn't that give the value of the contour integral instead?

Comment: The EMF is induced around the entire loop. It's all relative motion, so there shouldn't be anything special about the bar.

Comment: @AaronStevens what do you mean by the emf is induced around the entire loop? Doesn't that mean the emf from any arbitrary point going around and back to itself? However,I'm concerned with why the emf from the positive end to the negative end of the bar is also that value